# Closure versus classic class

Tags: javascript, class, closures

I'm using Node.js.

Could you tell where is the advantage of using this (closure):

```
function sayHello() {
    var num = 0;

    var sayAlert = function (val) {
        num++;
        console.log(num);
    }

    return sayAlert;
}
```

over this old classic one:

```
function sayHello2() {
    var num = 0;

    this.sayAlert = function (val) {
        num++;
        console.log(num);
    }

}
```

---

```
var ee1 = sayHello();
ee1(5);
ee1(6);

var ee2 = new sayHello2();

ee2.sayAlert(5);
ee2.sayAlert(6);
```

(shorter code perhaps for closure and more "JavaScipt way"?)

Comment: I don't know the real advantage of each one but by creating a object you can store variables as attributes within the object. Objects are advisable for complex codding, otherwise I think commom function are best.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like what you're really after is a function with a static counter. For that you can just use an immediately executing function.

```
var say = (function() {
   var num = 0;
   return function (val) {
      // Not sure why you're passing val here, it's not used
      num++;
      console.log(num);
   }
})();
```

Unless what you want is multiple counters, then you should use better names so it's clear to all who read it.

```
function createCounter() {
  var num = 0;
  return function () {
     console.log(++num);
  }
}
```

In the second example, you've implemented the same thing by using a counter on the closure of the constructor let's call it Speaker.

```
function Speaker() {
  var num = 0;
  this.sayAlert = function()  { 
    console.log(++num);
  }
}
```

They all do kind of the same thing

```
say(); say();  //outputs 1,2
var speaker = new Speaker();
speaker.sayAlert(); speaker.sayAlert(); //outputs 1,2
var speaker2 = new Speaker();
speaker2.sayAlert(); speaker2.sayAlert(); //outputs 1,2

var ctr1 = createCounter(); ctr1(); ctr1(); //outputs 1,2
var ctr2 = createCounter(); ctr2(); ctr2(); //outputs 1,2
```

Which one to use depends on whether you want a function or an object. And mostly whether you prefer to write functional or OO code.

Comment: *"...you don't need to call a function to return another function..."* But that's what you're doing in your answer. Do you mean you don't need to *name* a function? Or am I missing your point?

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't very clear. What I mean is that you only need to call it once, not every time you need a reference to it as the OP did in the example: `var ee1 = sayHello();` I guess one way to use this is if you want to have multiple counters, you'd instantiate multiple functions.

Comment: I see. Yes, I'd agree that there isn't much point in cluttering the environment with another name just to create a single counter. +1

Answer (score 2):

Neither is better. It depends on your needs.

They're nearly identical, except that one returns a function and the other returns an object that holds a function.

Answer (score 1):

The second example allows to have more than one method.

Comment: function sayHello() {
  var num = 0;

  return {
    sayAlert: function() {
   num++;
   console.log(num);
    }
  } 
 }
 
 var r = sayHello();
 r.sayAlert();